# Change Ubuntu 18.04 Nautilus context menu "Open in Terminal" from "Gnome-terminal" to "Tilix"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

Any idea on how may be changed context-menu from default `gnome-terminal` to `tilix` in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver?

Already tried renaming `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminalbackup`, then `/usr/bin/tilix` to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`, but without success, context-menu keeps running `gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a) Run `apt install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension`

b) Run `FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool`

c) File => New Action

d01) `Action` tab: Mark `Display item in location context menu`

[image: FileManager Actions a]

d02) `Command` tab:

- Path: `/usr/bin/tilix`
- Parameters: `--working-directory=%d/%b`
- Working directory: `%d`

[image: FileManager Actions b]

e) Restart Nautilus

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers didn't work for me, but using `python-nautilus` did the trick ([as seen here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/change-default-terminal-for-nautilus-open-in-terminal/131679/5)):

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install python-nautilus
```

Create the file `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/open-alacritty.py` with the following content:

```
import os

from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
        os.system("/usr/bin/alacritty --working-directory " + file.get_location().get_path() + "&")

    def get_background_items(self, window, file):
        item = Nautilus.MenuItem(name='NautilusOpenAlacritty', 
                                         label='Open in Alacritty', 
                                         tip='',
                                         icon='')
        item.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb, file)
        return item,
```

Restart Nautilus. When right-clicking inside a directory in Nautilus, you should now be able to see a new option "Open in Alacritty" above "Open in Terminal".

You can of course substitute `alacritty` for `tilix` or any other terminal emulator if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only answer that works on 21.04

Answer (score 0):

As Borba88 explained, you can use **FileManager-Action Configuration Tool** to append a `Open in...` entry in the contextual menu of Nautilus. Actually it allows you to bind any command to any context label (i.e., the entry/text displayed in the menu).

**Precision**: Actually, it requires another step to be really utilizable (i.e., on par with the default option in the contextual menu of Nautilus). You will probably want to remove the "FileManager-Actions" root menu, so it doesn’t take an extra click to open the (new) terminal:

To achieve this, just go in *Edit* > *Preferences* > And in `Nautilus menu layout`, unselect the option `Create a root 'FileManager-Actions' menu`.

You’re done. Congrats. ;-)

Btw, if you are looking for an efficient terminal, I suggest you to try [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty). Also [FileManager-Actions is in the AUR](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/filemanager-actions/) of Arch Linux.